# Declaring Math.toRadians

Tags: java, math

I need to get the horizontal and vertical movements of a vehicle using the speed, time and angle input. In my target class I have:

```
public double toRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);
public double getHorizontal() {
    return (speed*time*Math.cos(toRadians));
}

public double getVertical() {
    return (speed*time*Math.cos(toRadians));
}
```

however, the values of horizontal and vertical movement give me just the speed*time, so I assume there must be something wrong in the way I declared the math function?

Comment: What is `angle`? Where is that assigned?

Comment: it's a user input value.

  `public class vehicleMovement {

 private double angle;
 private double speed;
 private double time;`

Comment: My guess is that `toRadians` is 0. Your debugger would help you check this.

Comment: Don't post code in your comments. Post a [mcve]. What you have posted here is not enough to make sense of.

Comment: Both of your methods use cos. getVertical should use sin.

Comment: Oh yes, I did change the cos into sin for horizontal and it just shows 0, while for vertical it shows just the value of speed*time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something *not right* about your code.

Hint:  what is the difference between these two functions apart from their respective names?

```
    public double getHorizontal() {
        return (speed*time*Math.cos(toRadians));
    }

    public double getVertical() {
        return (speed*time*Math.cos(toRadians));
    }
```

Hint 2:  Suppose you plot a graph with `f(t)` on the X axis against `f(t)` on the Y access, and vary the values of `t`.  what will that graph look like?

---

> I assume there must be something wrong in the way I declared the math function?

The declarations are not the problem.  It is the function bodies that the problem.

(Though actually, it is a bit of the problem that, `speed`, `time` and `radians` (or `angle`) are instance variables rather than arguments to the functions / methods.  But deal with that problem after the problem with .... the formulae.)

Comment: Yes, I did notice that and changed it, but the values are still not printing properly

Comment: There are a variety of potential explanations.  Show us the relevant code.